# User Role Permissions in Security Token Claims in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, claims-based-auth, security-token-service

The Security Token for an FBA user (in SharePoint 2013 site) consists of the Role details also. What if the role has custom permissions defined in it. How do we get the Permissions of that role into a the Claims of the Security Token? Can anyone please help?